# R, how to tally by two columns?

Tags: r, aggregate, tally

My data looks like so,

```
    X  Y Goal
    32 12 1
    13 42 0
    55 33 0
    ...
```

I want to count how many goals in total were scored from each X-Y coordinate pairing. Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- read.table(text = "X  Y Goal
32 12 1
13 42 0
55 33 0", header = TRUE)

# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Group by both X & Y, then sum all goals
df %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Goal, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   X [3]
#>       X     Y Total
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1    13    42     0
#> 2    32    12     1
#> 3    55    33     0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! the 
df %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Goal, na.rm = TRUE))
was exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:(Better to provide expected output)

```
setDT(df)
df[,lapply(.SD,sum),.(X,Y)][]


   X  Y Goal
1: 32 12    1
2: 13 42    0
3: 55 33    0
```